# How do ObjectId's work, and can I just use them anywhere?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How do ObjectId's work, and can I just use them anywhere I need a unique id and trust that it will be unique?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on what you mean with "anywhere"? To ensure, that ObjectIds are unique, the  following information is used for creating the hash for the object ID:

- a unix timestamp
- machine hostname
- process id
- increment

see also the documentation at:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs explains `ObjectId`s. Because `ObjectId` contains a timestamp, machine ID, process ID, and incrementing counter, it should be safe to assume that it is unique each time you generate one.